# How to merge text files horizontally on a csv file?

Tags: linux, merge

I have several text files that consist of different values. I want to merge all of these files together horizontally and to output a csv file.

File.1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
```

File_2.txt

```
1 
2
6
7
8
.
.
.
```

Desired_output.csv

```
11 . . .
22
36
47
58
..
..
..
```

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste(1)` can do this:

```
$ cat letters
a
b
c
$ cat numbers
1
2
3
4
% paste -d , letters numbers
a,1
b,2
c,3
,4
```

Hmm, you say you want CSV but your output shows all the columns smooshed together which is not very CSV-like. Also `paste(1)` has trouble doing a no-delimiter thing. There is also `lam(1)` but it may not be standard.

```
$ paste -d '' letters numbers
paste: no delimiters specified
$ lam letters numbers
a1
b2
c3
4
```

Something more complicated will be required for CSV if the fields can contain the `,` character...